# How to algoritmically improve metric for k-nearest neighbors classification

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say I have a dataset with $n$ rows. The $i$th row ($x^i$) has entries $x^i_j$. For each $x^i$ I have an integer label, $p^j$.

New data comes along, with rows $y^i$, and I want to predict the corresponding labels $q^j$. To predict the label for a particular $y^i$, I calculate the distance between $y^i$ and all $x^j$s with metric $g$, ie $$D^j=g(y^i,x^j)$$
and the predicted label for $y^i$ will be $p^{\alpha}$ where $D^{\alpha}$ is the smallest of all $D^j$s.

This is the core of [k-nearest neighbors algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (with $k=1$ here).

How could I algorithmically use my original dataset to improve the metric $g$, so the predictions of the labels of $y^i$ rows are more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have [standardized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) the values first before using $L_2$ distance; that often helps.

If that's not sufficient, you could try using [metric learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning#Metric_learning).  But keep in mind that one of the appeals of k-nearest neighbors is that it is simple, so if you find yourself resorting to metric learning, it is possible that maybe nearest neighbors isn't the most appropriate classifier -- maybe you can find a better classification strategy.